# .NET Core dependency injection -> Get all implementations of an interface

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have an interface called `IRule` and multiple classes that implement this interface. I want to use the .NET Core dependency injection Container to load all implementations of `IRule`, so all implemented rules.

Unfortunately I can't make this work. I know I can inject an `IEnumerable<IRule>` into my ctor of the controller, but I don't know how to register this setup in the Startup.cs

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's just a matter of registering all `IRule` implementations one by one; the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI) library can resolve it as an `IEnumerable<T>`. For instance:

```
services.AddTransient<IRule, Rule1>();
services.AddTransient<IRule, Rule2>();
services.AddTransient<IRule, Rule3>();
services.AddTransient<IRule, Rule4>();
```

Consumer:

```
public sealed class Consumer
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IRule> rules;

    public Consumer(IEnumerable<IRule> rules)
    {
        this.rules = rules;
    }
}
```

NOTE: The only collection type that MS.DI supports is `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Are there any performance concern resolving IEnumerable<T>?  Like a dozen of them, comparing to inject an abstract factory then resolve individual service by name.  Thanks

Comment: @whoever: this is an impossible to answer question. You will have to measure this for yourself to determine whether or not the performance characteristics are okay in your particular environment. Measure, measure, measure.

Comment: @Steven  Thanks.  I just took another look.  Indeed, even the two cases I have are different.  In one, I loop through and call all implementations, so inject IEnumerable makes perfect sense; In the other, each caller only needs one particular implementation, but there are only two of them and init cost is negligible, kind of a wash.  So I decide the save the abstraction for another day ^_^

Comment: @steven How would you go about ordering the rules? Say i have rule1, rule2 and rule3. If you want the order as rule3, rule1, rule2. Perhaps in another section you want rule2 followed by rule1. One way i was thinking was to have a comma delimited list them loop the array and match against the rule name but it seems hacky. Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that this works fine with AddSingleton as well.

Comment: Don't omit the interface type (e.g. services.AddTransient<Rule1>(); services.AddTransient<Rule2>(); )

Answer (score 20):

For anyone else looking for an answer. You could also go through your assembly and register all classes that implement a specific interface:

```cs
// Get all implementations of IRule and add them to the DI
var rules = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && x.IsClass && x.GetInterface(nameof(IRule)) == typeof(IRule));

foreach (var rule in rules)
{
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IRule), rule, ServiceLifetime.Transient));
    // Replace Transient with whatever lifetime you need
}
```

This will also provide an `IEnumerable<IRule>` to every class that is part of your dependency injection. The advantage of this solution is that you do not need to add every single rule to your dependency injection. You can simply add a new implementation of `IRule` to your project and it will be registered automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this idea! You might want to consider using `IsAssignableFrom` instead of `GetInterface`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That would be even nicer. Unfortunately, it does not work. I guess the reason is that `IsAssignableFrom` refers to the reference, which cannot be resolved here. Therefore, the workaround via the name has to be chosen.

Comment: @Sebastian Not sure what you mean there. This works fine: `.Where(x => typeof(IRule).IsAssignableFrom(x));`

Answer (score 9):

Sebastian and Dennisch answers combined:

```
var rules = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
             .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && x.IsClass && typeof(IRule).IsAssignableFrom(x));

foreach (var rule in rules)
{
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IRule), rule, ServiceLifetime.Transient));
}
```

Also, note, you can use executing assembly to search for types.