# Get types implementing interface in ASP.NET Core web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to port some of my plain ASP.NET (MVC) code to the ASP.NET Core web application. My code looked like this:

```
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
       .Cast<System.Reflection.Assembly>()
       .SelectMany(
           a => a.GetTypes()).Where(type => typeof(IGoogleSitemap).IsAssignableFrom(type)
        )
        .ToList();
```

But I am not getting that to work on ASP.NET Core (1.1). For one thing Assembly does not have GetReferencedAssemblies() only GetEntryAssembly(). And GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies() gives me a list of AssemblyName instead of Assembly objects.

Basically I am looking for all controllers implementing the IGoogleSitemap interface (defined in a separate assembly).

Comment: Take at look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39569277/1256550

Comment: That requires explicit knowledge of the implementor (specific). My approach is to look for the IRule and then find all its implementors in all referenced assemblies. Got it figured out though. .NET Core is rather convoluted.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue though, I though this feature was only added in .NET Standard 2.0,
 how did you figure it out?
 (https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/919#issuecomment-305096783)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, .NET Core being so streamlined causes some things to be more complicated. I got it to work by changing the code to this (.NET Core 1.1)

```
IEnumerable<System.Reflection.TypeInfo> all = 
        Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().DefinedTypes.Where(type => 
              typeof(FullNamespace.IGoogleSitemap).IsAssignableFrom(type.AsType()));
 foreach (TypeInfo ti in all)
 {
     Type t = ti.AsType();
     // of all candidates filter out the actual interface definition
     if (!t.Equals(typeof(IGoogleSitemap)))
     {
            // do work here
     }
 }
```

Well, that does it for the Entry Assembly at least, still have not figured out how to do it for all *referenced assemblies* because GetReferencedAssemblies() returns AssemblyName rather than Assembly.

Comment: Thanks, great, I probably figured out a (possibly terrible an inefficient) way of do this for all referenced assembly, going to post that now (can't seem to paste the code here)

Answer (score 0):

I found a (terribly inefficient) way of achieving this,

```
var all =
        Assembly
        .GetEntryAssembly()
        .GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(Assembly.Load)
        .SelectMany(x => x.DefinedTypes)
        .Where(type => typeof(ICloudProvider).IsAssignableFrom(type.AsType()));
foreach (var ti in all)
{
    var t = ti.AsType();
    if (!t.Equals(typeof(ICloudProvider)))
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

I am worried about the cost of the `Assembly.Load` part, but this will probably get my work done for now - as I only need the Fully Qualified Name of all the classes that implements `ICloudProvider`.

Comment: Hey, it gets the work done. Maybe somebody out there would care to make it efficient but we can move on -as inefficiently as it may seem- for now.

Comment: Yeah good idea, until we migrate to .NET Core 2 let's stick to this! Thanks for the clue about `GetReferencedAssemblies` :)