# How can I use DI with Email and SMS classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have this interface:

```
public interface IMessageSender
{
    Task SendMessageAsync(parameters);
}
```

And this classes:

```
public class EmailSender : IMessageSender
{
}

public class SMSSender : IMessageSender
{
}
```

In my controller I have used them like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMessageSender _messageSender;
    public MyController(IMessageSender messageSender)
    {
        _messageSender = messageSender;
    }
}
```

And I have two methods in this controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendByEmail()
{ 
    await _messageSender.SendMessageAsync(parameters);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> SendBySMS()
{ 
    await _messageSender.SendMessageAsync(parameters);
}
```

In the above methods, how can I tell to the .net core that in the `SendByEmail` method, I need an instance of `EmailSender` class and in the `SendBySMS` method, I need an instance of `SMSSender` class. I have already added this to my startup class, but it clearly create an instance of `EmailSender` class always:

```
services.AddTransient<IMessageSender, EmailSender>();
```

Comment: There is no need to register IMessageSender if you don't need it. It is only if you need abstraction like "send it, and I don't care how". When you define IEmailSender, you mean "send it by email". There should be concrete intention behind every interface you define. At some point in time IEmailSender can receive other paramteres and diverge from IMessageSender completely.

Comment: The reason I suggest this approach is that the temptation for many people is 'these two classes do the same thing, so give them a common interface'. But generally with interfaces that is thinking about it the wrong way around. When thinking about interfaces, focus primarily on the caller. What does the **caller** want? If the caller wants to send emails - give them an interface to do that. If they want to send SMS - give them an interface to do that. They don't care about your abstractions - they care about sending emails or SMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have:

```
public interface IMessageSender
{
    Task SendMessageAsync(parameters);
}
```

and two classes that implement that interface. That does work, but I'd suggest a slight tweak to that approach. Keep `IMessageSender`, and add two new interfaces:

```
public interface IEmailSender : IMessageSender
{
}

public interface ISMSSender : IMessageSender
{
}
```

Why do this? Well, it now allows you to inject in a **specific** sender that you are interested in (this controller wants to send emails, that controller wants to send SMS).

Additionally, since they both inherit from `IMessageSender`, with some IoC containers (e.g. Autofac - I haven't tested them all) you could also inject a collection of `IMessageSender` (i.e. `IEnumerable<IMessageSender>`) - this is not *always* useful, but it can be useful if you want to invoke **all** of the message senders (i.e. SMS this **and** email this). If this is not useful - not a problem, remove `IMessageSender` altogether (and move the methods that define the interface into both `IEmailSender` and `ISMSSender`).

Now, change your classes to implement your new interfaces:

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
}

public class SMSSender : ISMSSender
{
}
```

and register your classes against both interfaces with your container. *With Autofac that would be something like `AsImplementedInterfaces`.*

Looking at your existing code, I'd suggest the below solution:

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
services.AddTransient<ISMSSender, SMSSender>();
services.AddTransient<IMessageSender, EmailSender>();
services.AddTransient<IMessageSender, SMSSender>();
```

Then change your controller to:

```
public MyController(IEmailSender emailSender, ISMSSender smsSender)
```

Comment: I think this `services.AddTransient<IMessageSender, EmailSender>();` is not correct because how can it distinct them later to create an instance from them? The farmer looks more correct to me. Isn't it?

Comment: That is useful if you want to inject `IEnumerable<IMessageSender>` (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/39569277/34092). You don't need it right now I suspect. Read `but it can be useful if` in my answer.