# C# DI Instantiation of container classes (IList, IEnumerable, ...)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Using dependency injection, how should one create an instance of a data container, like List, Dictionary, etc.

Given following example:

```cs
    public interface IXyz { }

    public class Xyz : IXyz { }
```

Is it against the style pattern to create a simple List? Like so:

```cs
    public class Abc
    {
        IList<IXyz> _data = new List<IXyz>();

        public Abc()
        {
        }
    }
```

Or should I use DI and let my container resolve the List for me? Like so:

```cs
    public class Abc
    {
        IList<IXyz> _data;

        public Abc(IList<IXyz> list)
        {
            _data = list;
        }
    }
```

Or something completely else?

Comment: Why does your class even need to have a list of something in its constructor? What type of concepts are these classes supposed to represent?

Comment: are you using .net core?

Comment: @AndrewE, yes I'm using .Net Core

Comment: @mason The class doesn't need it in its constructor, but in multiple methods inside the class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core dependency injection -> Get all implementations of an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567609/net-core-dependency-injection-get-all-implementations-of-an-interface)

Comment: @devNull No, I'm not trying to retrieve all implementations of IXyz.

Comment: @FlyingDutchman then what are you expecting to do by resolving a list of the interface with DI?

Comment: @FlyingDutchman You still haven't answered my question about what type of concepts these are supposed to represent. You've made your question too abstract. What is contained in an `IList<Xyz>`? Is it cached data? A collection of validators or logical rules?  You need to be specific about the scenario you're in, because the answers to the questions I've asked change the advice you'll receive.

Comment: This sounds like an XY, Problem to me.  Sorry, Bad Joke,  Just register  register everything normally, and request an `IEnumerable<IXyz>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to asnwer the question you should first answer the following questions:

1. Do you want `Abc` to make any decision on a lifecycle of `IXyz` implementations ?

   If the answer is **yes** - create a list of items inside `Abc`.
   Otherwise - use DI container.
2. Do `IXyz` implementations depend on any **cross-cutting concerns** of your system ?

   If the answer is **yes** - use DI container.
   Otherwise - go on and create/populate the list inside `Abc`