# .NET Core Built In Dependency Injection (DI): How can I not new up Dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am currently using the .NET Core built in Dependency Injection (DI).

My application is using the Rules Engine Design Pattern.

One of my rules, has a dependency, which has a dependency.  So, I have to keep on "newing up" instances of the dependencies. I feel as though there has be a better way.

Here is an example of my code.

This works but I don't like that I have to new up the DataService and the Repository.

```
var rules = new List<IRule>
   {
      new Rule1(),
      new Rule2(new DataService(new Repository(CnnStr))) //This is what I don't like
   };
s.AddTransient<IRulesEngine>(sp => new RulesEngine(rules));
```

I started setting this up:

```
s.AddTransient<IRepository>(sp => new Repository(CnnStr));
s.AddTransient<IDataService>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<DataService>());
```

Which seem to get me a little closer to what I want.  But, I have no idea how to populate the rules list with a list of instances of the rules with out having to have to new up the dependencies (DataService and Repo).

Something like this, but I know this code is not right.

```
var rules = new List<IRule>
   {
      s.AddTransient<IRule>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<Rule1>())
      s.AddTransient<IRule>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<Rule2>())
   };
s.AddTransient<IRulesEngine>(sp => new RulesEngine(rules));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567609/net-core-dependency-injection-get-all-implementations-of-an-interface

Comment: `s.AddTransient<IRule, Rule>(); s.AddTransient<IRulesEngine,RulesEngine>();` should just work so long as `RulesEngine` takes an `IEnumerable<IRule>`. No idea why you are trying to over-complicate everything.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks for the reply but I don't think you totally understand the situation (or I am misunderstanding you suggestion).  I can't do: s.AddTransient<IRule, Rule>(); or at least I don't think I can, because I have 2 Rules (Actually I am going to have about 20 rules).  All the rules implement IRule, but all have a different functionality.  Are you familar with the Rules Engine Design Pattern?

Comment: And the default DI container registers `IEnumerable<>` as an open generic. Any service that has an enumerable constructor argument, will receive all registered services.

Answer (score 3):

Register dependencies, required for rules

```
s.AddTransient<IRepository>(sp => new Repository(CnnStr));
s.AddTransient<IDataService, DataService>(); // you don't need sp here
```

Then register rules. `TryAddEnumerable` ensures that there will be no duplicated implementations of the same interface

```
s.TryAddEnumerable(new[] {
  ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IRule, Rule1>();
  ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IRule, Rule2>();
});
```

Register rules engine

```
s.AddTransient<IRulesEngine, RulesEngine>();
```

Note that rules engine should depend on `IEnumerable<IRule>`

Answer (score 2):

I got this working this morning.

I used a little bit from a lot of the responses.  But, the link below suggested by @Daniel A. White is what put it all together for me.

[.NET Core dependency injection -> Get all implementations of an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567609/net-core-dependency-injection-get-all-implementations-of-an-interface)

And maybe I was over-complicate as @Jeremey Lakeman suggested.

Here is the changes I made in my Program.cs file:

```
s.AddTransient<IRepository>(sp => new Repository(CnnStr));
s.AddTransient<IDataService, DataService>();

s.AddTransient<IRule, Rule1>();
s.AddTransient<IRule, Rule2>();

s.AddTransient<IRulesEngine, RulesEngine>();
```

Plus the changes I made to the Rules Engine:

```
private readonly IEnumerable<IRule> _rules;

public RulesEngine(IEnumerable<IRule> rules)
   {
      _rules = rules;
   }

public void RunRules()
   {   
      foreach (var rule in _rules)
      {
         rule.Execute(canonical);
      }            
   }
```